# OneToOne mapping: Referential integrity constraint violation

Tags: java, database, spring, h2, hibernate-mapping

I am in middle of developing a REST API using spring data JPA and need some assistance.

My REST API will process a request to create a Group and assign members to the group based on request data. The URL for the request will be `@PostMapping("/createGroup/{user-id}/groups")`

I have below classes,
Member class:

```
public class Member {

    private int memberId;

    private String memberName;

    private String memberCity;
// getters / setters
```

My Request Body class:

```
public class AppRequest {

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private List<Member> members;
// getters / setters
```

My GroupEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Groups")
public class GroupEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="groupOwnerId")
    private MemberEntity groupOwnerId;

    private String groupName;

    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name="Group_Members",
            joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="memberId")            
    )
    Set<MemberEntity> members = new HashSet<>();

// getters / setters
```

My MemberEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Members")
public class MemberEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int memberId;

    private String memberName;

    private String memberCity;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="members")
    Set<GroupEntity> groups = new HashSet<>();

// getters / setters
```

And finally My controller,

```
@RestController
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    MemberRepository memRepo;

    @Autowired
    GroupRepository groupRepo;

@PostMapping("/createGroup/{user-id}/groups")
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<AppResponse> createGroup(@RequestBody AppRequest request,
@PathVariable(name="user-id") String userId) {

        AppResponse response = new AppResponse();

        GroupEntity group = new GroupEntity();
        group.setGroupName(request.getName());
        group.setDescription(request.getDescription());

       // Code that causes error when trying to save owner ID
        MemberEntity mem = new MemberEntity();
        mem.setMemberId(Integer.parseInt(userId));
        group.setGroupOwnerId(mem);

        List<Member> members = request.getMembers();

        Set<MemberEntity> storedMembers = new HashSet<>();
        Set<GroupEntity> storedGroups = new HashSet<>();
        storedGroups.add(group);

        for(Member member : members) {
            if(member.getMemberId() != 0) { // existing member
                MemberEntity memberentity = new MemberEntity();
                memberentity.setMemberName(member.getMemberName());
                memberentity.setMemberCity(member.getMemberCity());
                storedMembers.add(memberentity);
                memberentity.setGroups(storedGroups);
                memRepo.save(memberentity);             
            }
            else { // new member
                //some logic
            }

            group.setMembers(storedMembers);
            groupRepo.save(group);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Request Body would be something like this,

```
{
  "description": "Funny Group",
  "members": [
    {
      "memberCity": "Mumbai",
      "memberName": "Amit"
    },
    {
      "memberId": 123
    }
  ],
  "name": "My Group"
}
```

What I want  to achieve is when a group is created, I want to add the user-Id in the REST URL [/createGroup/{user-id}/groups] as a owner ID for that group. To achieve this I am manually creating a member entity and setting that as a groupOwnerId as shown below,

```
MemberEntity mem = new MemberEntity();
mem.setMemberId(Integer.parseInt(userId));
group.setGroupOwnerId(mem);
```

If I comment above piece of code application boots up but the groupOwnerId value is set as null which is obvious as I am not setting it anywhere. So if I write above code, application boots up properly. But when I hit the endpoint, I get below error,

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKB0L8UXRYL2TEVI7BTCMI4BYOD: PUBLIC.""GROUPS"" FOREIGN KEY(GROUP_OWNER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.MEMBERS(MEMBER_ID) (12345)"; SQL statement:
insert into groups (id, description, group_name, group_owner_id) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
```

I am trying to figure out HOW I can do the mapping correctly, so that I can map the groupOwnerId from the URL. And also the new members gets saved into the database with auto generated IDs.

I am using H2 database at the moment but will eventually move to MySQL or Oracle.

Please let me know if you guys can help deciding the approach for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would use the following URL patterns for the group and user resources:

```
/groups/{groupId}
/users/{userId}
```

This will allow you to create users and groups separately, since a group can exist without any users and a user can exist without being member of a group.
As usual a POST operation to /groups/ to create a group and POST to /users/ to create a user.
After having created a group and a user, I would retrieve both the entities (or use the entities returned by the POST operations) to set a group owner of the group and create a JSON (or XML) representation of the group.
The JSON representation is then PUT to the URL /groups/{groupId} (with the actual id of the group inserted in the URL) in order to persist the group with the new group owner.
Hope this helps!

Comment: See, the user-id that comes a part of URL is nothing but the memberId, which is for already registered member who is in the system. In reuestbody, if there is id field, it means existing user and no id field means new user. And I have to save them accordingly. So basically a group can consist of already present as well as new members which needed to be saved in Members table. And the request body will always have the same format given above. So I cant split that into two separate calls.

Comment: Personally, I would redesign my solution to allow for separate creation of users and groups. Not only does it feel more natural to me, but apparently the design I suggest avoids the problem you seem to encounter.
Requiring a group owner when creating a group is feasible with the design I suggest but users still need to be created before creating a group.

Comment: The requirement I am working on involves member creation on the go along with the group. That's the dynamic approach considering that members can not always be available in system while creating the group.